# Connect NSSplitViewController to window

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard, nssplitview, nssplitviewcontroller

I want to connect my NSSplitViewController to my window in the storyboard of Xcode interface builder:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Right clicking on the blue box (window controller) and drag from window content to the NSSplitViewController:[image]

With no content set it will show up as a small line which that can expand but you might miss it if you have a lot of things on screen.